# Comparison of the elements of two sequences and their distribution limits

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Assume that we have two sequences of positive integrable r.v. $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ defined on the same probability space. Next assume that 
$$
X_{n}\stackrel{d}{\to}X
$$
and
$$
Y_{n}\stackrel{d}{\to}Y
$$
and let $E[X] < E[Y]$. Does this mean then 
$$
P[\liminf_{n\to\infty}\{X_{n} \leq Y_{n}\}] =1
$$
or
$$
P[X_{n}\leq Y_{n}] \to 1 \text{ as } n\to\infty
$$
?

Comment: No, not at all. why would you expect this?

Comment: Forget the series and limits.  It is entirely possible for $E[X] < E[Y]$ but $P(X<Y) < 1/2$ (in fact $P(X<Y)$ can be arbitrarily close to 0).

Comment: Even almost sure convergence of the sequences does not imply $P[X_n\leq Y_n] \to 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can construct a counterexample fairly easily; consider a case where $X_n = X$ and $Y_n = Y$ for all $n$; then, your task is only to construct variables $X, Y$ where $\mathbb E[X] < \mathbb E[Y]$, and yet $X > Y$ with positive probability. If you want, you could even do this in such a way that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.